# Find any Action in VS-Code (like in Intellj)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Intellij based IDEs (like PyCharm) have the nice feature `Ctrl+Shift+A`

> Find Action
>
> Find a command and execute it, open a tool window or search for a setting.

Does something like this exist in VS-Code, too?

For example I want to search/find this keyboard shortcut settings:

[image: keyboard-shortcuts--vscode]

But I would like to avoid to use the menu, I would like to use autocomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl + Shift + P` will do the trick!

Docs: [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)

Comment: Thank you! I already tried it. But I removed the `>` since it looked like a bug to me. If you remove the `>` then it only searches for open files. Slowly vscode and I become friends :-)